# Why doesn't solidity have 'sizeof' keyword like python have?

Tags: solidity

I want to know how can I use sizeof keyword.

---

is it reserved keyword? i found it in the solidity documentation.

Comment: someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I think possibly a kind core developer could chime in with a more authoritative opinion on the rationale but I can provide an intuitive opinion.

The EVM differs from general-purpose computing in that compute power is

- scarce,
- expensive (gas cost) and
- limited (block gasLimit) but,
- counter-intuitively, roughly instantaneous for most practical, application-related purposes.

This is roughly the opposite of desktop, server or handheld on which compute power is

- plentiful,
- essentially free, and
- limitless but
- The more you do, the longer it takes.

These differences have profound implications for contract design. You want to avoid unbounded recursion or iteration. Generally, you have to limit the maximum computational complexity of any operation to be sure it is *possible* for transactions to complete in any circumstance that can possibly arise. O(n) and O(log n) complexity are usually too much. You want O(1) complexity. You will find yourself moving mountains and designing data structures to ensure that is always the case.

So, while it might make sense, in Python, to optimize a process that wanders all over the place gathering stats, perchance to run faster or more conveniently than a hand-crafted process, such algorithms are to be avoided on the EVM. This might help: https://blog.b9lab.com/getting-loopy-with-solidity-1d51794622ad

You can get the length of a `string`, or `bytes` or the number of members in a dynamic array with `.length`. This will *always* access a single stored `uint256` value and return it - one step, so O(1).

In summary, you should probably reconsider your theory of operation if you think you need such a thing. Find a way to eliminate the need for it.

Hope it helps.